# What is $H_{n-1}(M - p)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am given a closed oriented, connected $n$-manifold $M$ and I want to compute $H_n(M-\{p\};\mathbb{Z})$ for some $p \in M$.  I tried writing down the L.E.S for the pair $(M,M-\{p\}):$
$$0 \to H_n(M- \{p\}) \to H_n(M) \to H_{n}(M,M-\{p\}) \to H_{n-1}(M-\{p\})$$
which becomes:
$$0 \to H_n(M- \{p\}) \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to H_{n-1}(M-\{p\})$$

I'm not sure where to proceed from here.

Edit: $H_n(M- \{p\}) =0$.  This follows from showing that the map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is injective.

Comment: You have no knowledge about that group. Luckily, you don't need it. Use excision.

Comment: Oops, I wanted to compute $H_n(M - \{p\})$.  I think it ends up being trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Like all noncompact connected manifolds, $M \setminus \{ p \}$ satisfies $H_n(M \setminus \{p\}; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$. You can also see it with the LES of the pair $(M, M \setminus \{p\})$, because you know that $H_n(M)$ is generated by the orientation class, which by definition is mapped to a generator of the local homology group $H_n(M, M \setminus \{p\})$.

On the other hand $H_{n-1}(M \setminus \{p\}) = H_{n-1}(M)$. Using the LES again:
$$H_n(M) \to H_n(M, M \setminus p) \to H_{n-1}(M \setminus p) \to H_{n-1}(M) \to H_{n-1}(M, M \setminus p)$$
The first map is an isomorphism, thus $\ker(H_{n-1}(M \setminus p) \to H_{n-1}(M)) = 0$. Moreover it's known that $H_{n-1}(M, M \setminus p) = 0$ thus $H_{n-1}(M \setminus p) \to H_{n-1}(M)$ is in fact an isomorphism.